# When extend SpringBootInitializer,why should i override configure method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As we all know,to publishing Spring Boot war,we should extend SpringBootServletInitializer and then override configure method like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I comment the overrided configured method,and then the application run without any exception.Then,why should i override the configure method,what is the usage of it?

Answer (score 4):

> The main method initializes an application context via a factory
>   method inside SpringApplication. It is using Spring Boot’s SpringApplication.run() method to launch the application.  The **configure** method inherited from
>   SpringBootServletInitializer does essentially the same but only when
>   deployed as a war file.